# Elastic Search Java Rest Client support for query template

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not able to find any support for query templates in Elastic Search Java REST Client (High Level). Does it exists? Or is there a way to use REST client with query templates?

Comment: Strikes us that we're on our own.